# It can't have been John vs. it couldn't be John

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

Let's say John is out of the country for a holiday. Then, Martha is claiming that she saw John this morning to Paul. Then Paul said:

> It **can't have been** John you saw this morning, he's out of the country for a holiday.

Vs.

> It **couldn't be** John you saw this morning, he's out of the country for a holiday. (My construction)

Are they both **grammatical** and **the same** in context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're both grammatically correct. A semicolon would be more correct between the two independent clauses in each example.

There's a subtle difference in meaning between the two.

- **can't have been** is definitive. You are sure that John is out of the country.
- **couldn't be** introduces some doubt. You certainly believe John is out of the country, but perhaps he snuck back in.

Check out [this answer on can't vs. couldn't](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38140/cant-versus-couldnt-what-is-the-difference) for more.